# How make eye and nose bigger or smaller in opencv and python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, dlib

I used the following code to select nose in OpenCV and Python i searched a lot of to find a way to change the size of nose and save as a other image but i didn't find anything is there anybody to help me to do this.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import dlib
img = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
img = cv2.resize(img,(0,0),None,0.5,0.5)
imgOriginal = img.copy()

detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
predictor = dlib.shape_predictor("shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat")

def createBox(img,points,scale=5):
  bbox = cv2.boundingRect(points)
  x,y,w,h = bbox
  imgCrop = img[y:y+h,x:x+w]
  imgCrop = cv2.resize(imgCrop,(0,0),None,scale,scale)
  return imgCrop


imgGray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
faces = detector(imgGray)
for face in faces:
  x1,y1 = face.left(),face.top()
  x2,y2 = face.right(),face.bottom()
  imgOriginal = cv2.rectangle(img,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,255,0),1)
  landmarks = predictor(imgGray,face)
  myPoints=[]
  for n in range(68):
    x = landmarks.part(n).x
    y = landmarks.part(n).y
    myPoints.append([x,y])
    #cv2.circle(imgOriginal,(x,y),5,(50,50,255),cv2.FILLED)
    #cv2.putText(imgOriginal,str(n),(x,y-10),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL,0.8,(0,0,255),1)
  myPoints = np.array(myPoints)
  #nose points to select
  #nose_points = myPoints[27:35]

print(myPoints)
cv2_imshow(imgOriginal)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I think you need "Bulge" effects such as implode and explode. There are no implementation of these filters in OpenCV but, you can find other tools such as Wand(a python binding for ImageMagick) that have [implode/explode](https://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.6.7/guide/fx.html?highlight=implode).

Example (wand):

```
from wand.image import Image

with Image(filename="test.jpg") as img:
    img.implode(amount = -0.2)
    img.save(filename="destination.jpg")
    # img_array = numpy.asarray(img) --> you can convert wand.image.Image to numpy array for further uses
```

passing negative values into implode functions is equal to doing explode. So for magnifying effect use negative values.

There is one problem though: img.implode performs on the center of the image, so after you've found the face features(eye, nose, ...) you need to move your picture somehow to make the eye or nose to lie on the center of the image. After that you can simply use implode function.

Comment: Thnaks. But the bad pqrt is we can't set a center point. Idk why they don't add this basic feature.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way using a spherical (bubble) warp in a local region in Python/OpenCV.

```
 - Define region center and radius and amount of spherical distortion
 - Crop the image for that center and radius
 - Compute the spherical distortion x and y displacement maps and a binary mask
 - Apply the distortion maps using cv2.remap
 - Antialias the mask
 - Merge the distorted and cropped image using the mask
 - Insert that merged image into the original image
 - Save the results
```

Input:

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import math
import skimage.exposure

img = cv2.imread("portrait_of_mussorgsky2.jpg")

# set location and radius
cx = 130
cy = 109
radius = 30

# set distortion gain
gain = 1.5

# crop image 
crop = img[cy-radius:cy+radius, cx-radius:cx+radius]

# get dimensions
ht, wd = crop.shape[:2]
xcent = wd / 2
ycent = ht / 2
rad = min(xcent,ycent)

# set up the x and y maps as float32
map_x = np.zeros((ht, wd), np.float32)
map_y = np.zeros((ht, wd), np.float32)
mask = np.zeros((ht, wd), np.uint8)

# create map with the spherize distortion formula --- arcsin(r)
# xcomp = arcsin(r)*x/r; ycomp = arsin(r)*y/r
for y in range(ht):
    Y = (y - ycent)/ycent
    for x in range(wd):
        X = (x - xcent)/xcent
        R = math.hypot(X,Y)
        if R == 0:
            map_x[y, x] = x
            map_y[y, x] = y
            mask[y,x] = 255
        elif R >= .90:    # avoid extreme blurring near R = 1
            map_x[y, x] = x
            map_y[y, x] = y
            mask[y,x] = 0
        elif gain >= 0:
            map_x[y, x] = xcent*X*math.pow((2/math.pi)*(math.asin(R)/R), gain) + xcent
            map_y[y, x] = ycent*Y*math.pow((2/math.pi)*(math.asin(R)/R), gain) + ycent
            mask[y,x] = 255
        elif gain < 0:
            gain2 = -gain
            map_x[y, x] = xcent*X*math.pow((math.sin(math.pi*R/2)/R), gain2) + xcent
            map_y[y, x] = ycent*Y*math.pow((math.sin(math.pi*R/2)/R), gain2) + ycent
            mask[y,x] = 255

# remap using map_x and map_y
bump = cv2.remap(crop, map_x, map_y, cv2.INTER_LINEAR, borderMode = cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, borderValue=(0,0,0))

# antialias edge of mask
# (pad so blur does not extend to edges of image, then crop later)
blur = 7
mask = cv2.copyMakeBorder(mask, blur,blur,blur,blur, borderType=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value=(0))
mask = cv2.GaussianBlur(mask, (0,0), sigmaX=blur, sigmaY=blur, borderType = cv2.BORDER_DEFAULT)
h, w = mask.shape
mask = mask[blur:h-blur, blur:w-blur]
mask = cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
mask = skimage.exposure.rescale_intensity(mask, in_range=(127.5,255), out_range=(0,1))

# merge bump with crop using grayscale (not binary) mask
bumped = (bump * mask + crop * (1-mask)).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8)

# insert bumped image into original
result = img.copy()
result[cy-radius:cy+radius, cx-radius:cx+radius] = bumped

# save results
cv2.imwrite("portrait_of_mussorgsky2_bump.jpg", result)

# display images
cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.imshow('crop', crop)
cv2.imshow('bump', bump)
cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.imshow('bumped', bumped)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Resulting Image:

[image]

Comment: Interesting. What do you think about whitening teeth? Can we also do it with CV2?

Comment: If you can locate the mouth/teeth, then they should be able to be whitened

Comment: I am trying to use dlib or MLKit face landmarks: https://developers.google.com/static/ml-kit/vision/face-detection/images/face_contours.svg
I can "get" them but how to "set" them after changing them?

Comment: Sorry, I do not know that software. But once you know the location of the mouth, you can draw a polygon connecting the mouth features and then convert the polygon to a mask that is white where the mouth is and black everywhere else. Then use the mask to whiten the mouth area.

Comment: I'll try it thanks. In your eye sample above, you already set the eye coordinates manually right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.